# Getting Storage Type from a blitz Array

Tags: c++, blitz++

I am using Blitz++ and doing some fancy wrapping.
The constructor for Array can take a storage type as one of the parameters. By default, this is `GeneralArrayStorage<N>()`. I have been looking through the documentation, but have not found any way to get the storage type from an array that has already been made. So, my question is: Is there an easy way to get the storage type for an array that can be used to build another array?

If it cannot be pulled out directly, is there an easy way to get the odering and ascending stuff to construct one with `GeneralArrayStorage<N>(ordering, ascending_stuff)`.
Thanks

Comment: It seems that there is no real good answer here. I may just try making a wrapper for blitz array to add the function `GeneralArrayStorage<N> storage() { return storage_; }`. Not my first choice... If it works (and `storage_` is maintained properly internally) I will post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The Blitz Array does seem to maintain the protected variable `storage_` properly. They must have seen no need to make it public... sadly. I have created a wrapper for the Blitz Array that adds a function for returning the storage. The added function is basically `GeneralArrayStorage<N> storage() { return storage_; }`. The class contains nothing else and inherits from `blitz::Array` publicly. If you can think of a better solution, let me know. Having a wrapper everywhere just to get one tiny variable is not my favorite solution.